# SQLAlchemy 2.0 Single Table relationship with base type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a object that I'm trying to set up a relationship to the base of a inherited model. The object in the table is one of the inherited objects (dataset), but even though I've set the relationship to the Base Object, the sub is what's returned. There's a bunch of expensive relationships in the sub, and I don't want them to be pulled across.

```py
class AccessRequest(Base):
    __tablename__ = "access_request"
    id = mapped_column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        server_default=text("gen_random_uuid()"),
    )
    created = mapped_column(DateTime, server_default=text("NOW()"))
    modified = mapped_column(DateTime, server_default=text("NOW()"))

    dataset_id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        ForeignKey(DatasetSummary.id, ondelete="CASCADE"),
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )

    dataset: Mapped[DatasetSummary] = relationship(single_parent=True)
```

and the related models:

```py
class DatasetSummary(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dataset"
    id = mapped_column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        server_default=text("gen_random_uuid()"),
    )
    access_type = mapped_column(String)
    contacts = relationship(
        "Contact",
        back_populates="dataset",
        uselist=True,
        passive_deletes=True,
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    )
    created = mapped_column(DateTime, server_default=text("NOW()"))
    draft = mapped_column(Boolean)
    label = mapped_column(String)
    summary = mapped_column(Text)  # raw text

    version_date = mapped_column(DateTime)  # manually set collection date
    version_label = mapped_column(String)

    ds_type: Mapped[str]

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": "ds_type",
        "polymorphic_identity": "DatasetSummary",
    }
 )


class Dataset(DatasetSummary):
    acknowledgements = mapped_column(Text)
    species = relationship(
        "DatasetSpecies",
        back_populates="dataset",
        uselist=True,
        passive_deletes=True,
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
    )
    ...
```

How do I get just the summary object (and not the larger inherited object) returned?